# Python was not found || Django set up on CMD

Tags: python-3.x, django, cmd

one day before **python manage.py runserver** command successfully executed & give the IP address of Server .Today gave *Python was not found error* .Please help me to fix

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer .Before executing runserver commmand of Django each time we need to excute

> **activate**
> command

[image]